# How to add Meta (Facebook) Pixel to web pages generated by Sphinx?

Tags: python, html, python-sphinx

I have obtained the **Meta Pixel** from Meta and I have a website made in Python documentation tool called **Sphinx**.

Now I need to add the generated code of Meta Pixel in the head section of my pages, right above .

The result should be like this:

```html
<head>
...

<script>Meta Pixel</script>
</head>
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find conf.py in your Sphinx source folder.
2. Check where is the folder for your templates. The default path is:

`templates_path = ["_templates"]`

In the templates folder, create a layout.html and paste the code you've gotten from Meta as shown below.

```
{% extends "!layout.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}

{{ super() }}

<!-- Meta Pixel Code -->


Put you Meta Pixel Code here!


<!-- End Meta Pixel Code -->

   
{% endblock %}
```

Similarly, you can add Google Analytics this way. However, Google insists on putting their code just below the <head> tag, which is impossible this way. But it seems to work anyway.